# Argument lifetime of an asynchronous function call

Tags: c++, asynchronous, argument-passing, lifetime

Herb Sutter in [GotW #91 Solution: Smart Pointer Parameters](http://herbsutter.com/2013/06/05/gotw-91-solution-smart-pointer-parameters/) states "
Thanks to structured lifetimes, the called function’s lifetime is a strict subset of the calling function’s call expression."
Does this apply to asynchronous function calls?

```
void myFunc(Bar * arg);
...
auto bar = new Bar;
std::thread t1(myFunc,bar);
delete bar;
join t1;
```

I presume that in this case, deleting bar could invalidate the argument passed into myFunc on thread t1.

Comment: There are no asynchronous function calls in C++. Threads are not functions, they are objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Here you're passing a *pointer* into the ctor of `t1` so all the structured lieftime related statements only apply to the pointer rather than the object it points to.

2) There are no asynchronous function calls here - you're calling a `std::thread` ctor and all structured lifetime statements apply to the ctor only rather than its side effects that eventually will make a call to myFunc.